# Equivalent to windows.h for mac

Tags: c++, macos

Is there any equivalent to windows.h for mac? 
I've been googling it but I can't find anything.
I don't know if it matters but I am currently using Mountain Lion.

Comment: There is no *single* header file on OSX which collects *every* OS API in the way windows.h (unfortunately) does. But OSX has its own set of headers and libraries exposing equivalent functionality. It's just differently (and better) structured -- and afaik, most of it is for Objective C, rather than C

Comment: <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>, which imports (among other things) AppKit.h, the one and only SDK for developing Mac OS X desktop apps.  There are numerous other frameworks available as well.  See /System/Library/Frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent. That is, no file for file substitute. It's a different platform after all. You will simply have to work with their API. And without knowing exactly what it is you want to do and what functionality you intend to use, it's hard to provide any additional information.

There is the Carbon API. Or better said, there was. Specifically since Mountain Lion, this API [has been deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/CarbonCoreDeprecations/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012224). The aforementioned link mentions some alternatives to deprecated functionality, though the Objective-C route might be a more easily manageable alternative.